# How to read email and retrieve attachement using CDO (Collaborative Data Object) in VB6?

Tags: email, vb6, attachment, cdo.message

Has anyone been able to download email that contains attachment with CDO in vb6?

Can you help me with an example?

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you look at CDO documentation and the stuff?

Comment: Hello, i can't seem to find examples or documentation of where it is used to retrieve emails, can you point me

Comment: Where do you want to get the email from? Are you talking about getting it from an Outlook server, or connecting to an Internet server?

Comment: I suspect this question is asked hoping that CDO (by itself) implements POP or IMAP client retrieval of email - which it does not.

Comment: @Beaner I have a code which uses cdo to send email direct through the email server, but am interested in direct retrieval in vb6. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure where you want to retrieve email from but here is some code for retrieving email from an Exchange server. I did this as an experiment to learn some methods I would need on another project so it is not production quality but should get you started. **This code is dependent on an Exchange client already being setup on the computer this is running on.**

This function creates a session and logs in:

```
Function Util_CreateSessionAndLogon(Optional LogOnName As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo err_CreateSessionAndLogon

    Set objSession = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
    objSession.Logon , , False, False
    Util_CreateSessionAndLogon = True
    Exit Function

err_CreateSessionAndLogon:
    Util_CreateSessionAndLogon = False

    Exit Function

End Function
```

This function get information on items in the inbox and demonstrates some of the available properties.

```
Public Function GetMessageInfo(ByRef msgArray() As String) As Long
    Dim objInboxFolder As Folder  ' Folder object
    Dim objInMessages As mapi.Messages ' Messages collection
    Dim objMessage As Message     ' Message object
    Dim InfoRtnString
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngMsgCount As Long

    InfoRtnString = ""

    If objSession Is Nothing Then
        If Util_CreateSessionAndLogon = False Then
            Err.Raise 429, "IBS_MAPI_CLASS", "Unable to create MAPI session object."
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Set objInboxFolder = objSession.Inbox
    Set objInMessages = objInboxFolder.Messages

    lngMsgCount = objInMessages.Count
    ReDim msgArray(0)   'initalize the array

    For Each objMessage In objInMessages
        If i / lngMsgCount * 100 > 100 Then
            RaiseEvent PercentDone(100)
        Else
            RaiseEvent PercentDone(i / lngMsgCount * 100)
        End If

        InfoRtnString = ""
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve msgArray(i)
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.ID
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.Subject
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.Sender
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.TimeSent
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.TimeReceived
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & "" 'objMessage.Text
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.Unread
        InfoRtnString = InfoRtnString & Chr$(0) & objMessage.Attachments.Count
        msgArray(i) = InfoRtnString
        DoEvents
    Next

    GetMessageInfo = i

End Function
```

This function demonstrates getting attachments from a message.

```
Function GetAttachments(msgID As String, lstBox As ListBox) As Boolean
    Dim objMessage As Message ' Messages object
    Dim AttchName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Long

    If objSession Is Nothing Then
        x = Util_CreateSessionAndLogon()
    End If

    Set objMessage = objSession.GetMessage(msgID)

    For i = 1 To objMessage.Attachments.Count
        Select Case objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).Type

            Case Is = 1 'contents of a file
                AttchName = objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).Name
                If Trim$(AttchName) = "" Then
                    lstBox.AddItem "Could not read"
                Else
                    lstBox.AddItem AttchName
                End If

                lstBox.ItemData(lstBox.NewIndex) = i

            Case Is = 2 'link to a file
                lstBox.AddItem objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).Name
                lstBox.ItemData(lstBox.NewIndex) = i

            Case Is = 1 'OLE object


            Case Is = 4 'embedded object
                lstBox.AddItem "Embedded Object"
                lstBox.ItemData(lstBox.NewIndex) = i

        End Select

    Next i

    GetAttachments = True

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this. i found an article, but its seems to depend on outlook. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978636.aspx.