# Retrieving Email from pop3 in WSH ?

Tags: vbscript, jscript, wsh

Is there a way to retrieve emails from a pop3 server in WSH ? 
My goal is to get attachement from email having specific sender / subject, and parse the file ...

I'm using microsoft CDO to send mail, but cannot fetch mail from a server.

I'd prefer a standart windows XP component if available.(no windows 7 yet where I work...)

Comment: That's not exact duplicate but may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/8293651/1856504

Comment: This require an exchange server. I'm looking for a pure pop3 scripted client (I dont think I even have outlook express on the pc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought my comment above will helps to answer yourself but as you still waiting...

> " I'm looking for a pure pop3 scripted client (I dont think I even
>   have outlook express on the pc...)"

Then the answer is NO. That's it, you need some POP or IMAP client installed 
to retrieve emails.